# pyarrow is failing to convert an "object" field

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I have a table that contains a few date values. When I do `data[['colname']].info()`, this shows that the field is an object field. This is how the `unique()` of the `data['colname']` looks like:

```
+-----------------+--------+
| 0    0000-00-00 |        |
+-----------------+--------+
| 1          None |        |
+-----------------+--------+
| 2    2022-07-22 |        |
+-----------------+--------+
| dtype           | object |
+-----------------+--------+
```

We can see that this is an object. When I try to convert to a pyarrow table. This is the code I used to convert it to a table:

```
import pyarrow as pa
pa.Table.from_pandas(data[['colname']])
```

It is throwing me this error:

```
ArrowTypeError: ("Expected bytes, got a 'datetime.date' object", 'Conversion failed for column colname with type object')
```

I searched other answers. We can workaround this by converting the values to a string object. My question is, if it is already in an object format. Why isn't pyarrow converting this to a table?

I tried googling and looking for other stack over flow answers. There were solutions to workaround it. But I want to know why pyarrow isn't converting an already object field.

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example with how to construct the pandas dataframe? 
You can also list other Stack Overflow answers that provide workaround for it?

Comment: Okay, looks like I found the reason why this is failing. In order to add a reproducible example. I did `df.to_dict( )`. Doing this, I figured out. That some values are just strings like `'0000-00-00'`, some values are of datetime formats like `datetime.date(2022, 7, 22)`.